# How much time will a pendulum lose in one day?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A pendulum clock beats every time the bob passes through its lowest point. What must be the length of the pendulum at a place where g= 32.0 ft/s^2? If the clock is moved to a point where g=31.0 ft/s^2, how much time will it lose in one day?

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula for mathematical pendulum

$$T_0 = 2 \pi \sqrt\frac{l}{g}$$

where $T_0$ is period of oscillation.  Clock beats every $T_0/2$ time, since bob passes through the lowest point twice every full swing.

I am amazed that someone is still using feet...